# How to pass parameters to next page when using ConfigurableNavigationHandler

Tags: jsf-2

How can I pass parameters to next page when using `ConfigurableNavigationHandler`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the parameters by appending includeViewParams=true to the outcome.

```
ConfigurableNavigationHandler configurableNavigationHandler =
         (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)FacesContext.
           getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

     configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("success?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true");
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to send an object after a redirect. You can use the Flash Scope for this purpose. 
    Objects placed inside the Flash scope will be available for the subsequent request and then cleared. 
    In other words, objects placed in Flash scope will survive a redirect.

```
context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ConfigurableNavigationHandler configurableNavigationHandler =
     (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

Flash flash = context.getExternalContext().getFlash(); 
flash.put("userBean", this);
configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("success?faces-redirect=true");
```

And use it on the outcome like this:

```
<h4>#{flash['userBean'].username}</h4>
```

See also:

- http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/

Comment: but I'd need to pass 1) customized objects as parameters 2) and these objects are the ones which are constructed by pulling the details from database and mapped to objects just before navigating using CongNavHandler.